# AJAX form problem

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have javascript as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("./index.php?menu=getmyFavList&ajax=ajax"
                   , {queryString: ""+inputString+""}
                   , function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>
```

And my corresponding php code is

```
$sql = "SELECT 
               u.UM_index
               , u.UM_first_name
               , u.UM_last_name
               , p.bz_pro_city
               , p.bz_pro_country
          FROM
               tbl_user_master As u
               , tbl_profile AS p
         WHERE
               u.UM_index = p.bz_pro_id
           AND
               UM_first_name LIKE '%" . $q . "%'
           AND
               UM_is_active = 'yes'                     
        ";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("unable to execute query");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$row['UM_first_name']
             . ' ' . $row['UM_last_name'] . '\');">'
             . $row['UM_first_name']
             . ' ' . $row['UM_last_name']
             . ',' . $row['bz_pro_city']
             . '</li>';
    }
```

And the HTML for is like :

```
<input type="text" name="reciever_name" size="37" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value)" onblur="fill()" />
```

Now my problem is I need to pass the `index` of the selected user which is in `tbl_user_master`. How can I do this (of course hiding the index from the sender)?

Comment: Please.. never pass a string to setTimeout. Use an anonymous function instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Why not put the `index` in an `<input type="hidden">` and add it to your `querystring`?</strike>

**Edit**
What you need to do is change what happens when a user selects an item.

In your `while` you'll need to change the `echo` to

```
echo "
    <li onclick=\"fill('{$row['UM_first_name']} {$row['UM_last_name']}'
                       , '{$row['UM_index']}')\">
        {$row['UM_first_name']} {$row['UM_last_name']}, {$row['bz_pro_city']}
    </li>"
```

And change your `JavaScript` `fill` function to

```
function fill(thisvalue, thisid){
    $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
    $('#selectedID').val(thisid);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

You'll also need to add

```
<input type="hidden" name="thisid" id="thisid" value=""/>
```

When the form is submitted, you would access the ID of the selected item using `$_POST['thisid']`

Comment: I tried to send it hidden filed : while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
  echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$row['UM_first_name'].' '.$row['UM_last_name'].'\');">'.$row['UM_first_name'].' '.$row['UM_last_name'].','.$row['bz_pro_city'].'</li>';
  
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="rid" value="'.$row['UM_index'].'" />';
 } But it shows the id of the last searched user !

Comment: I'm confused, what ID do you want to pass to your script via AJAX? Where does it come from?

Comment: Id of the user to whom one sends the message.It is in the table tbl_user_master.It means if you write echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$row['UM_first_name'].'\');">'.$row['UM_first_name'].$row['UM_index'].'</li>'; it is going to write first name of the user and the id of that user

Comment: So instead of adding `$row['UM_index']` to the `<li>` why not add it to `<input type="hidden" name="recipiantID" value="' . $row['UM_index'] . '" />`? You'll get the same result, w/o the index being seen by the end user.

Comment: But sir I need the id of the selected user,the above code returns the id of the last searched user from the search list !

Comment: ok, I think I get what you're looking for. What type of element is '#inputstring'? Is it an `<input>`?

Comment: Please update the question with that information instead of posting another comment.

Comment: The fill function not working. Means when I click on the names,it does not get displayed in the textboxt !

Comment: Then something is wrong on your end. The code I posted works [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/HQ9HD/1/)